# How to select text upon app loading?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

The title really says it all. I've tried selecting text from viewDidLoad in the following way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    guessField.text = "    "

    guessField.becomeFirstResponder()
    guessField.selectedTextRange = guessField.textRange(from: guessField.beginningOfDocument, to: guessField.position(from: guessField.endOfDocument, offset: -3)!)

}
```

However, this doesn't work; the cursor just appears in the last position. Does anyone have an idea to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it needs some time once your view loads. Try below solution:

First add below function in your class:

```
func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

Then use it in `viewWillAppear` method as shown below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    delayWithSeconds(1) {
        self.guessField.text = "    "

        self.guessField.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.guessField.selectedTextRange = self.guessField.textRange(from: self.guessField.beginningOfDocument, to: self.guessField.position(from: self.guessField.endOfDocument, offset: -3)!)
    }
}
```

I have just delayed it by 1 second.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works perfectly. Instead of delaying it 1 second, I just delayed it .01 seconds so it is as immediate as possible. Thanks again!